# c tcpclient connect error,about socket,and select

Tags: c, sockets

TcpClient:

First I know connect will failed, because I test ip-address is 127.0.0.1.

When I set sockfd id not block, then I start connect to server and set timeout = 6;
select will immediately return, then I test sockfd can read and write.

I can understand why the sockfd is writable, because when connect is failed,
the sockfd will write, but I can't understand why sockfd can read, the reason 
because the sockfd occur error, so it can read?

```
struct timeval st;
st.tv_sec = m_timeout;
st.tv_usec = 0;
fd_set rdset,wrset;
FD_ZERO(&rdset);
FD_SET(m_sockfd,&rdset);
wrset = rdset;
printf("m_timeout = %d\n",m_timeout);
ret = select(m_sockfd+1,&rdset,&wrset,NULL,m_timeout?&st:NULL);
if(ret == 0){
    close(m_sockfd);
    printf("connect timeout");
    return -1;
}        
else if(ret < 0){
    my_err("select error");
}
else{
    printf("ret = %d\n",ret);
    if(FD_ISSET(m_sockfd,&rdset) || FD_ISSET(m_sockfd,&wrset))
    {   
        int iError = 0;
        int iLen = sizeof(iError);
        if(getsockopt(m_sockfd,SOL_SOCKET,SO_ERROR,&iError,(socklen_t*)&iLen)<0 )    {
            return -1;
         }
        if(iError){
            errno = iError;
            printf("iError = %d,%s\n",iError,strerror(iError));
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("???\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
if(fcntl(m_sockfd,F_SETFL,flag) < 0){
    close(m_sockfd);
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `iLen` should be typed `socklen_t`. Doing you can drop the dangerous cast to `socklen_t*` when calling `getsockopt()`.

Comment: Probably a language issue, still I am having hard time to understand: "*...  ,because when connect is failed, the sockfd will write,but I can't understand why sockfd can read,the reason because the sockfd occur error ,so it can read?*"

Comment: The network programming book says: when connect returns failed, the socket becomes writable.buf not say it can readable,so i want to know why it can readadle?

Comment: If `connect()` fails it does **not** return a valid socket descriptor, so nothing is possible, no reading, no writing. Please exactly cite what you networking books states.

Comment: Your question seems to refer to code you do not show us. This does not simplify things ...

Comment: @alk，I'm sorry，My code doesn't show the problem I have to ask.i want to konow  why if(FD_ISSET(m_sockfd,&rdset) == TURE)? and i know why FD_ISSET(m_sockfd&wrset) is ture,thank you